# Plot multiple violin/box plots with variable width in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, violin-plot

I have a dataframe **trtime** containing the travel time (**Travel_time**) of certain trajects and plot them using a violin plot. I would like to plot each violin plot with a different width, how can I do this? I have four trajects (**Traject**) and have determined the desired with for each violin plot.

```
vplot <- ggplot( trtime, aes(x=Traject, y=Travel_time, fill=Traject, color=Traject ) ) +
    geom_violin()
```

I think factors are the way to go but am blocked on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vplot <- ggplot( trtime, aes(x=Traject, y=Travel_time, fill=Traject, color=Traject ) ) +
    geom_violin( scale="count" )
```

Adding option scale="count" will change the width of each violin plot relative to the number of entries in the plot.